# spring-saml IDPSSODescriptor wasn't found after time

Tags: java, spring, spring-saml

I have a system that works, but after certain period of time I have this kind of problem:

```
2017-08-31 15:31:00 ERROR UT005023: Exception handling request to /spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/login: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Metadata for entity ****** and role {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}IDPSSODescriptor wasn't found
2017-08-31 15:31:02,922 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-29) UT005023: Exception handling request to /spring-security-saml2-sample/: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:473)
```

My "express" solution is to restart wildfly but I'd like to resolve it definitively. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this same issue using CachingMetadataManager. In the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/saml/metadata/CachingMetadataManager.html), it says,

> Cache is cleaned whenever some of the providers published an observed
> message

My current guess is that the IDP either published a message and one of our severs didn't get it, or that the IDP made changes to the metadata without publishing a message. However, simply rebuilding the environment did fix the issue.